# jQuery: replace() in html()

Tags: jquery, html, replace

How can I replace html parts with `replace()`?

```
<div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var e = $("div"),
    fix = e.html().replace("google.com", "duckduckgo.com");
e.html(fix);
```

I guess html() is not working the same as `text()` ?

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/Hmhrd/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that `.replace` only replaces first occurence. If you want to replace all occurences, you must use a regular expression with a `g` (global) flag:

```js
var e = $("div"),
    fix = e.html().replace(/google\.com/g, "duckduckgo.com");
e.html(fix);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hmhrd/3/)

Remember you must escape [special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions) such as `.`, though. If you prefer, you can use

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(s1, s2) {
    return this.replace(
        new RegExp(  s1.replace(/[.^$*+?()[{\|]/g, '\\$&'),  'g'  ),
        s2
    );
};

var e = $("div"),
    fix = e.html().replaceAll('google.com', "duckduckgo.com");
e.html(fix);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hmhrd/4/)

Comment: Thanks. Saving `replaceAll()` just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

Make your pattern global by using the `g` switch:

```
var e = $("div"),
fix = e.html().replace(/google.com/g, "duckduckgo.com");
e.html(fix);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Hmhrd/1/)**

This way it replaces the link *and* the text.

Comment: *make your regex global*, OP isn't using regex at all ;)

Comment: OH! `replace()` only eats regex :/

Comment: @j08691, sorry to bug you, but again, he isn't using a *pattern*. Don't get me wrong though

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div a").attr("href", function (i, o) {
    return (/google/.test(o) ? "http://duckduckgo.com" : o)
}).html($("a", this).attr("href").substr(7))
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6rrKs/

Comment: This doesn't replace link's `href` attribute, though.