# Replace all characters in a string jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I replace all characters in a given string with `*` using the `replaceAll()` function?

```js
var words = ['marvel','computer','regex','throne'];
var rand = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
//should replace all characters in the string with *
$('#value').text(rand).replaceAll(rand,'*');
```

```css
.container{
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <input type='text' />
  <span id='value'></span>
  <hr />
  <button type='button' id='submit'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Id rather not go down the regex route but Im guessing I may have to.

---

Im writing a simple **hangman** program for fun that hides the string with `*` characters. The user then enters a character and if correct the character in the string is reset back to its original.

regex is great for stuff like this, im just not that familiar with it.

Comment: i guess you are correct. 
[see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325973/jquery-replace-in-html)

Comment: Why not just use regex? It's literally just `/./g `: https://jsfiddle.net/kz1m93d5/

Comment: You could loop through the string and replace each character individually, something like `array[string][counter] = '*';` (since you are storing your strings in an array)

Comment: @craig_h Im writing a simple 'hangman' program for fun that hides the string with * characters. The user then enters a character and if correct the character in the string is reset back to its original. regex is great for stuff like this, im just not that familiar with it.

Comment: @MasterYoda Ah, OK. Then I would just loop over the characters in the word to create the mask: https://jsfiddle.net/qqL9o129/

Comment: @craig_h awesome, looks like its something similar to Nenads answer below. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use regex you could use `split()` to transform string to array and then `map()` to modify each element based on condition.

```js
let replaceAll = (str, chars = []) => {
  return str.split('')
  .map(c => c.trim() && !chars.includes(c) ? '*' : c)
  .join('');
}
  
console.log(replaceAll('lorem ipsum', ['l', 'm']))
console.log(replaceAll('123    lorem ips', ['2', 'i'] ))
```

Comment: You're welcome, if for some reason you want to pass numbers in second parameter array and find then in string you then also need to map that number to string like so https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2520/

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to achieve what you want

```js
var words = ['marvel','computer','regex','throne'];
var rand = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
//should replace all characters in the string with *
var maskedRand = ''
for (var char in rand) {
  maskedRand += '*'
}
$('#value').text(maskedRand);
```

```css
.container{
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <input type='text' />
  <span id='value'></span>
  <hr />
  <button type='button' id='submit'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the form is doing, or how you're populating `words`. The reason I mention this, is if the array is being populated via a javascript function or jquery object, there may be a LOT of unwanted entries in the array. You may want to alter the below code to ignore those unwanted entries.

What this code is doing is looping through the `words` array and replacing each character (regex `/./g`) and replacing it with an asterisk (`*`).

```js
var words = ['marvel','computer','regex','throne'];
var rand = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
//should replace all characters in the string with *
for(var i in words) {
    words[i] = words[i].replace(/./g, '*');
}
console.log(words);
```

```css
.container{
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <input type='text' />
  <span id='value'></span>
  <hr />
  <button type='button' id='submit'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to replace the characters in random string that comes from the array rather than every word in the array?