# Is there a css option that links an html image to itself?

Tags: html, css, html-head

So this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            img{href:self}
        </style>
    </head>
    <img src="./Sampleimage"/>
</html>
```

would basically be the code I need, but since I don't know how or even if there is an option to do this, I figured, I have to ask someone more intelligent than me.

I kinda have to do this because I have about 200 images in this html Document, and every single one of them has to link to itself. So a seperate `<a>` tag for every image wouldn't be very stylish.

Comment: Well, that's not controlled by CSS as it's not a presentational aspect. You need `<a>` tag to be inserted programmatically. Why do you think a seperate `<a>` tag for every image wouldn't be very stylish?

Comment: What do you mean by "link to itself"? Have an `href` that opens up the `src` of the image in a new tab/window?

Comment: You could do this with pretty simple JS. Listen for a click event on your `img`, grab the src and open that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding off of WillardSolutions' comment...

```js
document.getElementById("myImg").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.open(this.getAttribute("src"));
});
```

```css
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" class="clickable" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif"/>
```

Open your browser console to see the opening of the URL being blocked...

If you want it to open in a new window/tab use:

```
window.open(this.getAttribute("src"), '_blank');
```

Comment: Only drawback with 200 images would be 200 event listeners that **might** potentially slow down the page. [Event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) would help

Comment: You probably should add `cursor: pointer` to the CSS for all images you do that for, so it's clear that the images are clickable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @jPlatte. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nice idea, but no, as the commenters above have explained.

What you can do is get the source URL of each image using jQuery and append it to the parent `<a>` element. I would do this on page load rather than on clicking the image, as then the images are ready to click.

I would also suggest using a thumbnail version of the image, otherwise it will take ages for the page to load. (If you do that, you will need to put all the thumbnails in a subdirectory and then remove that subdirectory from the link URL using a [replace function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325973/jquery-replace-in-html)).

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
  $("img").each(function(){
    var imgUrl = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).parent().attr('href', imgUrl);
  }); 
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/12/15/02/53/flower-3876195_960_720.jpg" width="200"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JS for this simple solution...

```
<a href="image-src.ext">
 <img src="image-src.ext"/>
</a>
```

if you want the image to be downloadable add the `download` attribute to `<a>`. It is really no problem and the faster performance solution. And about 'stylish'... forget about stylish in coding :D

Comment: I have ~200 Images. I dont think I'll do that for every one of them.

Comment: You place them by hand? Then use JS, for faster results. But I recommend using something like a flat file system and store ur image data somewhere and let PHP render the page with a and img tag for you. Have a look at GRAV Flat file CMS

Answer (score 0):

This might be the solution you are looking for.

Here is the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/RadekD/bgfpedxv/1/

### HTML

```
<img class="image" src="https://placeimg.com/100/200/nature" />
<img class="image" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature" />
<img class="image" src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/nature" />
```

### JS

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
    images.forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener("click",function(){
            window.location.assign(element.src);
        });
    });
```