# JQuery - open image on click

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to open an image on click with a simple JQuery.

I'm building on the code provided here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54040130/is-there-a-css-option-that-links-an-html-image-to-itself#:~:text=Nice%20idea%2C%20but,Expand%20snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54040130/is-there-a-css-option-that-links-an-html-image-to-itself#:%7E:text=Nice%20idea%2C%20but,Expand%20snippet)

Everything works fine. However, I want to add a detail: the image should open only if the parent  doesn't have an already defined href attribute. Differently the original href should open instead.
Now all the  parent of an image get overwritten. How can I avoid this?

On the code below, the first image should open itself. The second one should open the original href.
I want to avoid to use two different classes for the two images. It should be possible to override the href only if undefined using JQuery.
How can I do?

index.html

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<a><img src="image2.jpg" class="clickable"></a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="image1.jpg" class="clickable"></a>
```

script.js

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    $("img").each(function(){
        var imgUrl = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).parent().attr('href', imgUrl);
    }); 
    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the images that are children of anchors without an `href` attribute. The best thing is, you don't need jQuery at all for this

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a:not([href]) img").forEach((img) => {
  img.closest("a").href = img.src;
});

// this is just for showing the result
document.querySelector("pre").textContent = document.querySelector("div").innerHTML;
```

```css
/* This is just for the snippet, ignore it */
div { display: none; }
```

```html
<div>
<a>
  <img src="image2.jpg" class="clickable">
</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
  <img src="image1.jpg" class="clickable">
</a>
</div>

<pre></pre>
```

---

The jQuery equivalent doesn't look much different and IMO isn't worth using.

```js
$("a:not([href]) img").each((_, img) => {
  img.closest("a").href = img.src;
});
```

Comment: The solution without JQuery seems really elegant. But for some reason I cannot make it work.
I'm not totally sure of why you set the div display to none also.
Sorry, I'm quite new to JS, there is for sure something I'm getting wrong.

Also the JQuery solution doesn't work

Comment: Make sure your `<script>` is placed after the elements in the document, preferably just before `</body>`. See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/283366)

Comment: Ok, thanks, it works!
For some reasons if I reference the script in an external .js file it doesn't work,
but if I put the code directly inside the <script> tag everything works fine.
Do you know why?

Comment: I'm putting it before closing the </body>
For some reason this works:
```HTML
<script>
 document.querySelectorAll("a:not([href]) img").forEach((img) => {
  img.closest("a").href = img.src;
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```
This doesn't:
```HTML
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/open-image.js" defer></script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```
I've also tried some of the methods included in your link

Comment: Seems ok (except you have an extra `</script>` that shouldn't be there). Any errors in your dev-tools _Console_ or _Network_ panels? Also, try clearing your cache. Cached JavaScript files can be easily out-of-date

Comment: Thanks Phil! Now it works.
Probably a cache problem

Comment: @prb it usually is 

Answer (score -1):

PRB!

Here is one way to do it:

```js
$('document').ready( document ).ready(function(){
    $('img').each(function(){
        let url = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).wrap($('<a>',{
                href: url
        }));
    });
});
```

---

Explanation:

When the document is ready, it calls for each image tag and then gets the attribute of SRC, which is then added a parent `<a>` tag, which inturn is the URL for the image.

I hope this helps!

Comment: OP's `<img>` tags are already wrapped in `<a>` tags

Comment: @Phil Well, it helps...

Comment: Thanks fox tech!
I canot make it work.
I'll however for the pure js code Phil provided.
But I still have some issues with these scripts.